# Icons not appearing

Tags: javascript

Need to populate table rows with Edit & Delete Icons. Can get buttons on each row but unable to get icons. 
Populating table with data with JSOn

```
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data);    
var table = $('#register-data').DataTable({
    "data": jsonResponse.data,
    "columns": [
         { "data": "ReleaseID" },
         { "data": "ReleaseName" },
         {
           "data":null,      
           "defaultContent": "<button class='btn-Edit'><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</button>"
         },               
     ],                            
     "order": [[1, 'dsc']]                       
});
```

Font awesome called in index.html file

Any advise would be great

Comment: You've got a syntax error. If you open console you'll see it. Hint: Key "defaultContent", it's value has wrong quotation marks around one of the class parameters.

Comment: `"defaultContent": "<button class='btn-Edit'><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</button>"` - double quotes `"fa fa-edit"` inside the string need escaping or turning into single-quotes, this is breaking your JSON

Comment: @Car could you mark a correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error like this:

```
   "data": jsonResponse.data,
        "columns": [
        { "data": "ReleaseID" },
        { "data": "ReleaseName" },
        { "data":  null,      
          "defaultContent": "<button class='btn-Edit'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i>Edit</button>"
          }               
        ],                             
        "order": [[1, 'dsc']]                       
    });
```

Comment: The double quotes was my issues.  Thank you,  I hadn't spotted the error.

Answer (score 0):

As @ADyson pointed out there was a typo in the 'defaultContent' object I have your example with some dummy data only additional changes are consmetic

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var data = '{"data":[{"ReleaseID":1,"ReleaseName":"Jam"}]}'
var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(data); 
  var table = $('#register-data').DataTable({
           "data":jsonResponse.data,
          "columns": [
          { "data": "ReleaseID", "title": "ReleaseID" },
          { "data": "ReleaseName", "title": "ReleaseName" },
          { "data":  null,  "title": "Action",      
            "defaultContent": "<button class='btn-Edit'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i>Edit</button>"
            }               
          ],                             
          "order": [[1, 'dsc']]                               
  });
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable table table-striped" id="register-data">

  </table>
</div>
```

**Documentation:**

[Jquery Table API](https://datatables.net/reference/api/)